# Adding publishing page > why won't it retain page layout during provisioning

Tags: page-layout

After provisioning a site the new site does not have the right page layout like I instructed the code to be. I went to site settings of the new site and clicked on page layout and site template. And sure enough it was inheriting from parent instead of using what I told it to use. hmm. Can anyone see any fault in the code? The page layout pages shows in the list.

```
private static void AddPage(SPSite site, SPWeb web, string pageName, string strPageTitle)
{
  PublishingWeb publishingWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
  PageLayout[] pageLayouts = publishingWeb.GetAvailablePageLayouts();
  PageLayout currPageLayout = null;
  foreach (PageLayout pl in pageLayouts)
    {
     if (pl.Name.Equals("RMLayout.aspx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
          {
            currPageLayout = pl;
            break;
          }
    }
   PublishingPageCollection pages = publishingWeb.GetPublishingPages();
   PublishingPage newPage = pages.Add(pageName, currPageLayout);
   publishingWeb.Update();
   string content = "";  // "Welcome to <strong>My Page</strong>";
   newPage.ListItem[FieldId.PublishingPageContent] = content;
   newPage.Title = strPageTitle;

    newPage.ListItem.Update();
    newPage.Update();
    newPage.ListItem.File.CheckIn("System Checkin");
    newPage.ListItem.File.Publish("System Published");
}
```

Comment: Does the code execute all the way through? Can you be sure that currPageLayout` is not null when you create `newPage`?

Comment: In dev it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overlooked the fact that I had to turn on the "Site Feature" so that webprovisioned event receiver kicks in. There were no bugs to fix.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the part that it looks like is missing from your code:

```
// Create a list of page layouts
ArrayList newPageLayoutList = new ArrayList();
foreach (PageLayout pl in pageLayouts)
{
  if (pl.Name.Equals("RMLayout.aspx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
  {
    newPageLayoutList.Add(pl); // add your pagelayout to this list
  }
}

// Assign your new list as the available page layouts
publishingWeb.SetAvailablePageLayouts(newPageLayoutList.ToArray(), false);
```